# The rationality of a condition from the 1st law in an infinitesimal thermodynamic process

Tags: thermodynamics

Statistical Physics of Particles by Mehran Kardar, Sec. 1.7

> **Enthalpy** is the appropriate function where there is no heat exchange ($dQ=0$), and the system comes to mechanical equilibrium with a constant external force.

```
  .................
```

> For any set of displacements x, at *constant (externally applied)* generalized
> forces $\bf{J}$, the work input to the system is $dW\le\bf{J}\cdot\delta\bf{x}$. (Equality is achieved for a quasi-static change with $\bf{J}=\bf{J}_i$, but there is generally some loss of the external work to dissipation.) Since $dQ=0$, using the first law, $\delta E\le \bf{J}\cdot\delta\bf{x}$, and $$\delta H\le 0, \text{ where } H=E-\bf{J}\cdot\bf{x}$$ is the enthalpy.

Most thermodynamic quantities are well defined only for states in equilibrium. If the process is not quasi-static, the quantities $H,\bf{x}$ are generally meaningless. On the other hand, the quantity $\bf{J}$ is the constant **external** force rather than a property of the system, hence cannot be in the expression of $H$, and the condition $\delta H\le 0$ is a little  bit doubtful.

Is there any reasonable explanation?

Comment: How does your reasoning applies to specific example $\mathbf{J}d\mathbf{x}\rightarrow pdV$?

Comment: Are you asking why $dW\le -pdV$?

Comment: I mean the statement: *On the other hand, the quantity $p$ is the constant external force rather than a property of the system, hence cannot be in the expression of $H$, and the condition $\delta H\leq 0$ is a little bit doubtful.*

Comment: Well, $\delta H=\delta E+\delta (\bf{p}\cdot\bf{V})$, but the 2nd term $\delta(p\cdot V)\neq p\delta V$ because in non-quasi-static process, there's no well-defined $p$ for the  system. The reasoning in the book is based on the fact $p$ is constant, which is external pressure.

Comment: I think what matters here is that any changes of $H$ are due to work, since $dQ=0$ - whether the process is quasistatic or not. $H$ is not a function of a process, but of a state.

Comment: You are right, I'm confused about the expression of $H$ which finds external force $\bf{J}$.

Comment: I don't understand the authors rationale for the inequality in $\partial H\le 0$ for a non quasi-static process since $H$ is a state property.